# PHP pageName pulling from other page

Tags: php

I'm working on my script site I have the url setup like this with PHP.

movies.php?pages=action

But every time a member goes to the url it pulls the page name from movies.php how can I fix this issue I have pasted my code down below.

```
<?php
// StreamPlex Page System - Play Page
DEFINE("IN_STREAMPLEX", 1);

$pageName = "All Movies";

require_once('inc/config.php');

require_once('inc/header.php');

$action = $_GET['action'];
$pages = $_GET['pages'];

if(isset($pages)) {
     require_once("{$pages}.php");
} else {

?>
```

Then at the bottom of the page I have finished off with this code here

```
<?php include 'inc/footer.php'; ?>

<?php } ?>
```

Can somebody please help me in telling me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What is it you're doing wrong... Not reading the data from a database for start.

Comment: I have the database information stored inside the inc/config.php i figure it out i had move the code around a little now its all working :)

Comment: Glad to hear that you managed to get working. You can self-answer your question and describe in detail what went wrong, or delete it so other users not answer a problem that is now solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fix the issue i had change around the code at the top of the page from

```
<?php
DEFINE("IN_STREAMPLEX", 1);

$pageName = "All Movies";

require_once('inc/config.php');

require_once('inc/header.php');

$action = $_GET['action'];
$pages = $_GET['pages'];

if(isset($pages)) {
     require_once("{$pages}.php");
} else {

?>
```

To this

```
<?php
// StreamPlex Page System - Play Page
DEFINE("IN_STREAMPLEX", 1);
$action = $_GET['action'];
$pages = $_GET['pages'];

if(isset($pages)) {
     require_once("{$pages}.php");
} else {

$pageName = "All Movies";

require_once('inc/config.php');

require_once('inc/header.php');
?>
```

Now it works in loads with no problems.